# Algorithm for decomposing a complex (self-intersecting) polygon into simple polygons

Tags: computational-geometry

I've been attempting to write a Bentley-Ottmann sweepline algorithm to transform a self-intersecting (complex) into a set of simple polygons.

There are some instructions on [this page](https://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html#Bentley-Ottmann-Algorithm) (see the heading entitled "Decompose into Simple Pieces") however my current implementation is falling short (see img below).

[image: Current result]

While I'm able to find all the self-intersecting points I'm not able to construct the desired outputs when there are multiple self-intersections on a single segment.

Here is what I'd expect to get
[image]

I'm struggling to find any other papers which describe the process or required data structures in any more detail. The blog post references a linked list which could mean a [Doubly Connected Edge List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) although I'm not 100% sure, the other challenge with that is that I don't think there is a suitable js implementation of that data structure.

Any advice on how I might reconstruct the desired output would be appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify what part of your solution is incorrect? It looks like your non-simple polygon it is decomposed into 2 simple polygons. I do not think a DCEL is needed here, the algorithm probably simply means a list.

Comment: Hi @Discretelizard . I've clarified the expected output above in the question. But yes good observation that I have in-fact got two simple polygons - I hadn't actually noticed :)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what part of the algorithm you want more explained. It seems that 2 of the 3 intersections shown have not been correctly processed (if they have been processed at all), but I don't think you need me to tell you that. Put another way, try to formulate a clear question about the algorithm. Currently, I don't see what prevents you from implementing the algorithm, other than that you appear to have some bugs. However, note that debugging an implementation is off-topic here.

Comment: I was hoping someone might be able to point me to a paper or additional information which described the steps in additional detail.
At the moment I'm going off a few dot points on one blog and as far as I can tell I'm doing what it's asking but it's not working...
So I appreciate it's not a clear question @Discretelizard - if I knew exactly what was going wrong I wouldn't be here :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a thesis on exactly this topic:

> Subramaniam, Lavanya. "Partition of a Non-simple Polygon Into Simple Polygons." Master's
>   thesis, University of South Alabama, 2003.
>   [PDF download](https://web.archive.org/web/20100805164131/http://www.cis.southalabama.edu/~hain/general/Theses/Subramaniam_thesis.pdf).

---

[image: Fig10[1]]

          

<sup>Fig.10f, p.23.</sup>

---

Comment: Thank you @joseph-orourke . I've seen this paper however it seemed to differ in approach from the blog post above which would mean rewriting what I have thus far which I'd like to avoid :)